# How to resolve the error Pacakge_Path_Not_Exported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, package.json, echarts

I tried:

```
yarn start
```

I got this error in the terminal:

> yarn run v1.22.19
> warning ....\package.json: No license field
> $ react-scripts start
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:571
> throw e;
> ^
> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in C:\Users\abize\Echarts-in-React\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\postcss\package.json
> at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
> at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:361:10)
> at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:697:9)
> at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:565:36)
> at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:634:31)
> at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:27)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\abize\Echarts-in-React\my-app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
> code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
> }
> Node.js v18.16.0
> error Command failed with exit code 1.
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

This is my pacakge.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": ">=7.21.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "echarts": "^5.4.2",
    "echarts-for-react": "^3.0.2",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I thought there was a problem with the package postcss-safe-parser so I tried to fix the problem by clearing the yarn cache using `yarn cache clean`, manually permanently deleting the node modules, reinstalling the dependencies using `yarn install` and rerunning `yarn start`. This did not work and I got the same error message again.

Can anyone help me fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I got this (and one more issue) fixed by updating my import statements, found hints to do this in the documentation of npm packages (dependencies with issues).

FROM this:

```
const uniqueId = require('uuid/v4');
const HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');
```

TO this:

```
const { v4: uniqueId } = require('uuid');
const { HttpsProxyAgent } = require('https-proxy-agent');
```

Of course it might be some other issue for the author, but maybe this will help someone in the future, who knows =)